# Long-pressing power button shows Assistant, how to restart the device?

Tags: reboot, google-pixel, buttons, google-assistant

The long press on the Power button that I used on my earlier Android (Oreo) is now popping up the assistant. So what is the secret gesture?

This is for a Pixel 7 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Pixel Device

<kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>volume up</kbd>  pressed simultaneously will give you options to restart amongst others

[image]

Note: You won't find the *bug report* option unless you enable it from developer options (enabled by tapping build number 7 or more times)

---

For Samsung users. the gesture is <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>volume down</kbd> , per this [comment](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/253145/long-pressing-power-button-shows-assistant-how-to-restart-the-device/253146?noredirect=1#comment343128_253146)

Comment: For Samsung users. the gesture is Power + Volume Down, instead of Power + Volume Up

Comment: @CSM, thanks , added your inputs to the answer

Answer (score 6):

**Long pressing the power button is still the standard gesture to show the power menu, including the restart option.** However, the Assistant is likely due to the system gesture setting.

At least for Pixel devices with Android 12 or later: Settings  → System → Gestures → Press and hold power button → Hold for Assistant.

| Toggle | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Off | Press and hold for the power menu |
| On | Press and hold for the Assistant |

Note that [since Pixel 6, the default is set to on (Assistant)](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/7172657).

Comment: This is new for me// I don't use assistant so this is easier!

Comment: From what I can recall, at one point they changed long-press to ONLY do Assistant, and only later added the option to change it back. I spent quite awhile very annoyed about this.

Comment: @beeshyams Yeah, I just noticed that it's been turned on by default since Pixel 6.

Comment: @GlennWillen I didn't find any info about that though. It would be helpful if you could provide some more info, like which device model and Android version.

Comment: @AndrewT yes, confirm on 6a and therefore likely on OP's phone

Comment: Note that not all phones have this setting. My phone (Moto G71 5G, stock android) doesn't have this setting as it has a separate button for the assistant. The power/lock button by default does show the power menu on long hold.